# Comparing django template strings

Tags: django, django-templates

The value of word_group.group and w.group is "Test 1"

However, the following output for:

```
{% for w in words %}
     {% for word_group in word_groups %}
        {% if word_group.group == w.group %}
            True
        {% else %}
            {{word_group.group}} : {{w.group}}
        {% endif %} 
     {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```

is: "Test 1" : "Test 1"

why is the if comparison failing?

Comment: This might be a unicode vs str issue. Have you checked what type both `word_group.group` and `w.group` are?

Comment: They might not be string types at all, but model instances with `__unicode__` methods that return those strings.

Answer (score 5):

Adding stringformat filter worked for me in the same situation.
Look for the example below, I've added the template filter

```
{% for w in words %}
     {% for word_group in word_groups %}
        {% if word_group.group|stringformat:"s" == w.group|stringformat:"s" %}
            True
        {% else %}
            {{word_group.group}} : {{w.group}}
        {% endif %} 
     {%endfor%}
{%endfor%}
```